# Em Clean Architecture, qual camada recebe as regras de negócio e lógicas específicas de um sistema?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, arquitetura-de-software

Falando de Clean Architecture, normalmente se vê exemplos de um sistema básico de CRUD, mas que não mostram onde ficam localizados os códigos de Controllers que precisam de uma complexidade um pouco maior do que simplesmente um CRUD.

Por exemplo:

Um controller deve cadastrar um usuário mas, antes, ele precisa ver se o usuário já existe, verificar se a senha digitada está de acordo com as regras de segurança, entre outras coisas que poderiam ser citadas nesse exemplo.

Acredito que a resposta será que essa lógica fica na camada "Application" porém, mais especificamente onde?
Seria dentro das classes Service? A mesma que contém os métodos padrões do CRUD (add, remove, update, List, etc) ? Ou seria criando um novo Service para esse tipo de lógica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia, Na verdade não, A camada onde ficam as regras de Negócios,é a camada chamada entidade, no seu projeto ela vai ser as models que vc vai fazer para inserir na base de dados. Por exemplo é o arquivo onde vc define quais dados vão ter nas tabelas e como eles vão se relacionar.

Depois dela vem a camada chamada Use-cases,No seu projeto ele vai ser o repositório, que é aquela camada que faz a conexão com a Base de Dados e insere as Models que vc definiu na BD,gerando o que a gente chama de migrations.

A camada mais Externa são os Controllers,Esses sim, que vão se comunicar com A entidade,fazendo operações essenciais do CRUD,A unica ibrigação que o Controller vai ter é pegar informação ou enviar informação.

No seu projeto,seriam os endpoints que vc modela, e as requisições REST que vc faz.

E por fim, tem a UI, que é a user interface,que apenas vai consumir todos os dados que o controller traz.

Nessa camada TBM fica a DB que vai se comunicar com o Repositorio.

[image: clean-architeture]

Comment: aqui segue uma image do livro Arquitetura Limpa

https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fimasters.com.br%2Fback-end%2Fintroducao-clean-architecture&psig=AOvVaw1MNSqS7V_jtuhzPM0RHPed&ust=1613584134866000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJCLjvD67u4CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD